# Vertex problem: there are some dark shade in the view mode

Tags: vertices, extrude

[image: now it is like a belly..]I try to build a hole and extrude today. And I come across with this problem.
Does anyone know how to fix it?

[image: inview mode]
[image]

Comment: Did you try Alt+N - Recalculate Outside? This can be normals facing problem, or it may be some topology issue as well

Comment: Yes Miko I tried. But still the same..

Comment: Is it possible that you have duplicate vertices?  (Try selecting all and then M, merge at center.)

Comment: @MartyFouts I tried.. still not working..

Comment: Solved!! Thank you guys..
I rebuild it and give ut more Bevel on the part that intersact.
Finally work